# dynamically set endpoint in fine-uploader

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I would like to set the request endpoint of fine-uploader dynamically.
For example:

```
$('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
      request: {
        endpoint: submitUrl
      },
      multiple: false,
      button: $("#uploader-button"),
      // etc...
  });
```

submitUrl must be already set in the page and can't be changed.
I would like to do something more dynamic, something like:

```
 request: {
        endpoint: function() { ($('#submitUrlField').val() }
      }
```

But the above sends the request to 
function%20()%20%7B%20$(%27#submitUrlField%27).val()%20}

Grateful for anyone who knows how to do this!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

your old code:

```
 request: {
        endpoint: function() { ($('#submitUrlField').val() }
      }
                               |_ why need ( becasue it has not close ) match
```

try one of these

```
request: {
   endpoint: function() { return $('#submitUrlField').val() }  // here you had `(`
}
```

or

```
request: {
   endpoint: $('#submitUrlField').val() 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I also had to remember not to define the jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader directly in `$(document).ready(function () {` but in a function that is called after I change the value of submitUrlField

Comment: The endpoint option does not accept a function as a value, so only the last example will work.

Comment: Also note that Fine Uploader provides a setEndpoint API method that allows you to set the endpoint for all files or a specific file at any time after the Uploader instance has been created.  See the [methods documentation page](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/methods.html) for details.

Comment: @Ray Nicholus. Your comment about the setEndpoint API method should be an answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multi enpoints. 
For example use several endpoint for odd/even uploads:

```
        callbacks: {
            onUpload:  function(id, name) {
                var endpoint = endpoints[id % endpoints.length];
                this.setEndpoint(endpoint.url, id);
                this.setParams({
                    signature: endpoint.signature,
                    params: endpoint.params,
                    ajax: true
                }, id);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can replace `uploader` with `this` if you'd like as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if my eyes were deceiving my when I first read your answer, but there are a number of issues with it that I see now. Why did you add a global variable (bad)? Why is your endpoint url not a url? Why are you logging to the console when a comment is more appropriate in this context?

Comment: @RayNicholus it just a example ;)

Comment: ...but why would you ever want to set the endpoint to "odd" or "even", or perform a modulus on the id? It seems like noise to me. Reducing this to the single call to setEndpoint seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is big and you have enabled the chunking, you can't change the endpoint url dinamically.
My solution is use the event

```
callbacks:{
  onComplete:function(id,name,responseJSON,xhr) {
    console.log('> onComplete. id=' + id);
    console.log('> onComplete. name=' + name);
    console.log('> onComplete. responseJSON=' + JSON.stringify(responseJSON));
    console.log('> onComplete. uuid=' + responseJSON.uuid);

    if (responseJSON.success)
    {
      // call a httpRequest with the url you want.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One useful example for the `setEndpoint` method. This code will set endpoint based on uploading file type:

```
    callbacks: {
        onUpload:  function(id, name) {
            var file = this.getFile(id);
            var fileType = file.type;
            this.setEndpoint(endpointList[fileType], id);
        }
    }
```

Your `endpointList`:

```
var endpointList = {
    'image/png': 'url/uploadimage',
    'video/mp4': 'url/uploadvideo',
    'text/plain': 'url/uploadtext'
}
```